# Forward Outlook email without adding signature nor From: and To: of original email

Tags: vba, outlook

I'm looking to forward email that I receive in Outlook to a new address with no changes - an exact clone, no envelope information nor signature added.

The email will always have an HTML table in the body and needs to be preserved identically. I can get it to forward but it always adds a blank email body with a signature "above" the original email, and then there is the standard From: and To: and email attributes above the original email.

Is there a way to remove this? I have tried to change this to generate a "new" object, as the new object is not bringing in the HTML body before forwarding.

```
Sub Send_Forward(ByRef oMail As Object, repBodyStr As String, sendMail As 
Boolean)

Dim myForward As Object                   

Set myForward = oMail.Forward
myForward.Subject = myForward.Subject

myForward.HTMLBody = repBodyStr & "<br>" & myForward.HTMLBody
myForward.Recipients.Add "xxx@xxx.net"

myForward.Display


ExitSub:

Set myForward = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new item (`Application.CreateItem`), then just copy the HTMLBody property from the existing message and add the recipients.

UPDATE: if you need to copy the attachments (such as images), you would have to save the attachments from the original message (`Attachment.SaveAsFile`), then add them as attachments to the new message (`MailItem.Attachments.Add`). Note that this will not work with embedded OLE objects (in case of the RTF format) and embedded message attachments. For the images, you would also need to copy the `PR_ATTACH_CONTENT_ID` MAPI property using `Attachment.PropertyAccessor`.
Also note `MailItem.Copy` would not work as the message sent state will be copied (which his not what you want).

If using [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption) (I am its author) is an option, it allows to make a copy of the message without copying its sent state. Something like the following should do the job (off the top of my head):

```
Set Session = CreateObject("Redemption.RDOSession")
Session.MAPIOBJECT = Application.Session.MAPIOBJECT
set originalMsg = Session.GetRDOObjectFromOutlookObject(Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection(1))
set newMsg = Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderDrafts).Items.Add
'copy the message and clear out recipients
originalMsg.CopyTo(newMsg)
newMsg.Recipients.Clear
newMsg.Recipients.Add "xxx@xxx.net"
newMsg.Save
'now reopen the message in OOM and diplay it. Or you can use newMsg.Display
set myForward = Application.Session.GetItemFromID(newMsg.EntryID)
myForward.Display
```

Comment: Hi Dmitry, I have this working with Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection(1) and some other tweaks. However, the pictures in the HTML Body are not preserving.

The table in HTML preserves, but the pictures are now "The picture can't be displayed".

Also, can you confirm if this will now iterate through each message? I am testing now. Thank you!!

Comment: Ugh - playing whack-a-mole on the issue now. I cannot get this to iterate through each message. I am not sure if it is a problem with where I have the call for this sub placed? Or something with the sub itself. If I have 4 items in the folder, the macro is properly autoreplying individually to each of the 4, but it is only sending the new message "forward" for the topmost item in the queue (newest item when sorted by date) and then not processing for the rest of the items.

Comment: thank you Dmitry, I am trying this now. Currently finishing up changes to ensure the code continues to the next item, as the previous iteration of my code only processed on the item in the selection cursor (not desired behavior)